# Putting values from an Increment in C++ into Excel

Tags: c++, excel

I am trying to put my answers gained from this increment;

```
for(int i=0; i<=n; i++)
  {
  Xnew = -i*(Y+R1)/n; //calculation for angles and output displayed to user

  Ynew = pow((((Y+R1)*(Y+R1)) - (Xnew*Xnew)), 0.5);

  cout<<"\n("<<Xnew<<", "<<Ynew<<")"<<endl;

  AngleB = acos(Xnew/pow((pow(Xnew, 2))+(pow(Ynew, 2)), 0.5))*(180/Pi);

  cout<<"\nAngle 'B' = "<<AngleB1<<" Degrees"<<endl;

  AngleV = acos(((pow(Xnew, 2))+(pow(Ynew, 2))+(pow(100, 2))-(pow(65, 2)))/(200*(pow(((pow(Xnew, 2))+(pow(Ynew, 2))), 0.5))))* (180/Pi);

  cout<<"Angle 'V' = "<<AngleV<<" Degrees"<<endl;
  AngleTheta1 = AngleB - AngleV;

  cout<<"Theta 1 = "<<AngleTheta1<<" Degrees"<<endl;

  AngleTheta2 =(asin(pow(((sin(AngleV*Pi/180))*(pow(((pow(Xnew, 2))+(pow(Ynew, 2))), 0.5))/65), 0.5)))*(180/Pi);

  cout<<"Theta 2 = "<<AngleTheta2<<" Degrees"<<endl;

  }
```

Now, depending on what value the user chooses for 'n', then a list of 'n' number of values will appear. E.G. So I will get 2 co-ordinate (Xnew, Ynew), and 4 different angles if n = 2.

Now, we are having trouble inputting these values into Excel, where a table of values with headers would appear. We have tried to write in CSV. format, but we only succeeded in getting Excel to display one value in each column, and not the list of values that we wanted (when n>1).

We were given this code by a postgrad helper for our project which still hasn't really helped.

```
// writing on a text file
   #include <iostream>
   #include <fstream>
   using namespace std;

   int main () {
   ofstream myfile ("h:\\test\\files\\example.txt");
   if (myfile.is_open())
   {
       myfile << "This is a line.\n";
       myfile << "This is another line.\n";
       myfile.close();
   }
   else cout << "Unable to open file";
   return 0;
   }
```

So, does anyone have any suggestions on how to put our calculated values onto Excel, displayed in the format I specified above? Thanks again, hope the question is clear enough.

Here roughly the code we tried before (though we did delete it so may not be perfect) when we got the broken single values to appear.

Under int main(){

```
 std::ofstream file_out("Test.csv");
```

and at the bottom (Underneath all the code)

```
 file_out << "x, x2, x3" << std:endl;
 file_out << x << ", " << x2 << ", " << x3 << std::endl;
```

But x, x2, and x3 were all the values specified above (i.e. AngleB, Xnew, etc. )

Comment: I think what you mean is replace cout with myfile?

Comment: Don't use '\\' as a path separator, use '/'. Please.

Comment: Looks a lot like a question from @RoryFermor yesterday. Can you show your code that created the broken 1-column csv file?

Comment: @NickSlash, updated it with what we tried

Comment: You dont appear to have any new lines in there? unless that is what `std:endl;` is for. Any chance you can upload or paste an example of your failed csv file? You might just need to import it differently.

Comment: You mean the code, or the Excel results file? @NickSlash the std:endl; is for new line I think.

Comment: The CSV file yes, if you could upload it somewhere for us to look at.

Comment: Okay, sorry, might sound really stupid here, but how do I upload it? Short of posting our entire code on the question.

Comment: Link to it. Use dropbox, rapidshare, any number of free upload providers.

Answer (score 0):

You are going to need a table of values rather than a list for this to work

remove all your cout instances and replace with something like the following.

```
cout<<AngleB1<<" "<<AngleV<<" "<<AngleTheta1<<" "AngleTheta2<<" "<<endl;
```

You coule write your list of headers to the file before the loop runs